# Javascript/jQuery safe selected item for next page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem and don't find a way...
I have 30 items on each site.

A user can select one, two or more, (or also all) and go than to the next page, select the next ones (up to 30) and go to next page and must be can select more if he wants.

How can I save the Items with class "active" that I have this in a cookie or something when he is on the next page and something?

After he is done, I have a button where I must read out all selected items.

This is how an item looks like (my HTML)

```
<div id="items">
  <label class="item active" data-itemid="12345">Item1</div>
  <label class="item" data-itemid="12345">Item2</div>
  <label class="item" data-itemid="12345">Item3</div>
</div>
```

If someone clicks on an item, the class action is added to the label where he clicks. Like the first one.

This was my try

```
var items = [];
$('#items .active').each(function(i, obj) {
     items.push($(this).data('itemid'));
});
app.setcookie('itemselected', JSON.stringify(items));
```

It saves every with active class, but the problem is, when I go to the next site, he delete everything selected on the first site and overwrite with every selected (active) item from the current site...

The Cookie looks like `12345, 123456, 1234567` 
That is okay, but when I go to page 2 and start to select/activate next items, then overriding my old ones

And also, when he unselect an item, this itemid must be deleted from the array/cookie

Comment: Better to use `localStorage` for something like this, because it's information that only the client needs, not the server.

Comment: for me it looks like you're always starting with a clean array on each page `items = []`. You should retrieve previously stored values (from cookie or storage) first and push them into `items`

Comment: What does "when I go to the next site" means ? What is happening when the user click on next page ? How do you currently activate an item on click ?

Comment: Every page loads 30 items. Next Page start on offset 30, than next 30 items and that... Every Item has unique itemid, so on 2nd page other ids than on the first page

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to get started...

```
// Save Local Data
var items = [];
$('#items .active').each(function(i, obj) {
    items.push($(this).data('itemid'));
});
localStorage.setItem("active_items",  JSON.stringify(items));

// retrieve data
var localData = localStorage.getItem("items");
if (localData){
    items = JSON.parse(localData);
}
```

You can view locally saved data in the chrome inspector Application tab under Storage>Local Storage